# rewiterule for changing url

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

If someone hit the url like this : `http://mydomain.com/action/login/uname/sudip/pass/md5(password`)

How can my system convert it `http://mydomain.com/index.php?action=login&uname=sudip&pass=md5(password)`?

Please give a rewrite rule for this.

Comment: why are there functions in the url?

Comment: and I HIGHLY recommend to NOT pass passwords in the url (not even hashed!)

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /your/directory/path/

RewriteRule ^(.*)action/(.*)/uname/(.*)/pass/(.*)$ index\.php?action=$2&uname=$3&pass=$42%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: I think this should be like this RewriteRule ^action/(.*)/uname/(.*)/pass/(.*)$ index\.php?action=$2&uname=$3&pass=$42%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess file in DOCUMENT_ROOT directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# your rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^(action)/([^/]*)/(uname)/([^/]*)/(pass)/([^/]*)$ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [L,QSA,NC]
```